# Exoplayer live streaming - efficient source switching

Tags: android, performance, http-live-streaming, exoplayer2.x

My android app navigates through a series of http live streams using remote control.
I use a TreeMap to store streams as tv channels, with channel number as key.
The code below is the function that open/changes source url.
I was wondering if you could suggest a more clean and efficient way to quickly switch to another source. Also possibly decrease load time of the next source.

```
private void playUrl(String url) {
    Uri videoUri = Uri.parse(url);
    DefaultBandwidthMeter bandwidthMeter = new DefaultBandwidthMeter();

    try {
        player.stop();
    } catch (Exception e) {

        TrackSelection.Factory videoTrackSelectionFactory = new AdaptiveTrackSelection.Factory(bandwidthMeter);
        TrackSelector trackSelector = new DefaultTrackSelector(videoTrackSelectionFactory);

        player = ExoPlayerFactory.newSimpleInstance(this, trackSelector);
        PlayerView simpleExoPlayerView = findViewById(R.id.player_view);

        ////Set media controller
        simpleExoPlayerView.setUseController(false);//set to true or false to see controllers
        simpleExoPlayerView.requestFocus();
        // Bind the player to the view.
        simpleExoPlayerView.setPlayer(player);
    }

    // Measures bandwidth during playback. Can be null if not required.
    // Produces DataSource instances through which media data is loaded.
    DataSource.Factory dataSourceFactory = new DefaultDataSourceFactory(this, Util.getUserAgent(this, "CanaliTV2"), bandwidthMeter);

    MediaSource videoSource = new HlsMediaSource(videoUri, dataSourceFactory, 1, null, null);
    // Prepare the player with the source.
    player.prepare(videoSource);
    player.setPlayWhenReady(true); //run file/link when ready to play.
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Its a difficult and complex subject, and one that I have been looking at myself recently.

When you call prepare on the player, its effectively restarting it. So any resources the player is currently using (could be renderers and codecs, drm sessions etc) are released and then recreated for the new stream. At which point the data source needs to fetch the data.

By continuing to call prepare for each channel, the only way really to improve start up time for playback after switching 'channel' is if the new data source is cached in some way in anticipation of the switch.

I think that in order to do that you'll need your own data source factory. The simplest way to write your own is to start by copying the source of the default into your own class and then begin to work out what changes you need to make in order to fulfill your requirement.

Now you can play around with LoadControl cache values to determine just how much data will be downloaded prior to playback and in doing so you'd try to minimise unnecessary data transfer, at the same time as begin playback as quick as possible. - about 2.5s is generally recommended (Exoplayers DefaultLoadControl provides this value out of the box), but you may be able to get away with less depending on how good the content cdn is.

But in actual fact, a better and more efficient way to do it, would be to not have to call prepare each time. And so yYou might be able to manipulate the players playlist by adding new MediaItem instances. see [here](https://exoplayer.dev/playlists.html) for more details.

In theory, you could actually add all channels MediaItems to the same player, and then when a user changes the channel, you could seek to the start of the next MediaItem. This would then mean that the player won't need to re-instantiate all the required resources which may be more efficient for you.

This answer is my opinion and I may not be providing best practices, but as I said, I've investigated something very similar recently, with little success in any hard fact on how to complete my task. and so this was the rough outline of what i had come up with.

Hope it helps. (sorry its a bit wordy)

Comment: Thank you for reply. The first solution may not be optimal, since I don't know what will be the next source the user will switch to, they can be accessed randomly. I need to study the second solution, even if I'm not sure how it applies on live sources

Comment: did you get any efficient solution for this?